# Angularjs - highlight field when field not valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and would like to know how I can highlight form fields when the validation fails.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/9DTmq/3/) to illustrate what I'm after.

Any help is appreciated.

```
     <p>
        <label for="name">User:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name"
               required  ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="32">
    <span ng-show="register.name.$error.required" class="err">
        Required</span>
    <span ng-show="register.name.$error.minlength" class="err">
        Minimum 5 characters</span>
    <span ng-show="register.name.$error.maxlength" class="err">
        Maximum 32 characters</span>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your case, you could try ng-class:

```
<input type="text" ng-class="{highlight:register.name.$error.required || register.name.$error.minlength || register.name.$error.maxlength}" name="name" ng-model="name"
                   required  ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="32">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9DTmq/4/)

Another solution is to style on these classes:

```
ng-valid
ng-invalid
ng-pristine
ng-dirty
```

Angular automatically toggles these classes based on current validation status. Below is the demo to hightlight invalid inputs:

```
input.ng-invalid { 
    background:#F84072;
    border: 2px red solid;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9DTmq/5/)

Comment: If the second solution doesn't work for you try override following css class:
`.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    border-color: red;
    outline-color: red;
}`

Comment: @Enigo: this has a different meaning. It applies for invalid AND dirty inputs.